# SharePoint Online 2013 Workflow to change file permission in Document Library?

Tags: workflow, permissions, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, visual-studio-2012

1.What are my options with SPD 2013 If I want to change file permission in a workflow?

2.Where does SPO host 2013 Workfows?

3.If connecting to SPO Can I use Worklow Manager 1.0?

4.Will I need to host my Workflow Manager workflows on server or Azure if running against o365/SPO?

5.If I wish to create SPO 2013 workflows with Visual Studio 2012, what do I need and will I be limited to actions I see in SPD 2013?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2013 workflow for SharePoint Online doesn't support management of list and document library permissions. To change permissions from workflow you can use 3rd party activities. For now I know only [Workflow Activity Pack for SharePoint Online](http://plumsail.com/workflow-activity-pack/), developed by my team.